# set Power Query display folder for a query column in M?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a number of very wide datasets in Power Query - hundreds of columns each (don't ask).  I am trying to determine if (how) to assign columns to display folders programatically.  I have access to some data that I could use to assign the display folder based on the column name.  Some research into the metadata functions in M is tantalizing but I have not found the silver bullet example yet.  Has anyone attempted this?

I've done some basic research and written some bits of M to look at the metadata functions, but that's about it.  I was hoping someone might have the magic function call needed to set the display folder, or know if it is even possible.

Comment: Can you explain what "assign columns to display folders " means? Are you trying to grab data from a directory that gets specified as a variable?  Do you have a sample image showing what you want to do?

Comment: You cannot do this with M. The display folder property is part of the data stored in the SSAS instance, and can be accessed through tools like DAX Studio (which also allows scripting, so you could use that to set things programmatically, as well as pure XMLA/JSON on the SSAS endpoint), but M has nothing to say about it. It would be *possible* for Power BI to use some metadata assigned to the column to set the display folder, but (as far as I know) it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  To horseyride, the power query dataset is pulled from an application database that has data regarding custom forms and fields on those form that the app hosts.  I want to organize my dataset columns (i.e. the custom form fields) in the same manner, as the users understand this categorization.   To Jeroen - thanks for the idea.  I had thought this might be exposed as an SSAS property, being somewhat familiar with SSAS and DAX, but had not looked into leveraging that yet.  Now I will.  Cheers!